# Supply gradient to FindMinimum subject to constraints

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

FindMinimum supports explicitly supplying the gradient (as well as the Hessian) via the `Gradient` (resp. `Hessian`) option. However, this seems to only work for the objective function. Is there a way to provide gradients for the constraints as well?

This is very useful in case Mathematica would need to resort to expensive to compute finite differences but the gradient would be readily available by some means.

My guess is that this is not supported because the constraints can be given by an arbitrary Boolean combination of (in)equalities and thus some normal form would be required to match the structure of the `Gradient` option to the constraints.